# how to match a string in whole array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array in javascript

```
var arr = ["12","22","33","42"];
```

1. If I search for 1 it should not match because it is not a complete array element.
2. If I search for 12 it should match because it is a complete array
   element.

I have searched web for this but found

```
var match = arr.indexOf('1');
```

But this does not solve my problem

Anybody can help?

Comment: It looks like indexOf seems exactly what you need. Maybe you can elaborate on why it doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: indexOf should work. So if it doesn't work I would suggest posting your code. And remember that indexOf returns -1 if not found. You can read about indexOf here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: +1 to Felix -- also, just to be clear indexOf returns -1 when there is no match.

Comment: If indexOf doesn't work, then either you're doing something wrong or you're not phrasing your question correctly

Comment: If you want a boolean return value, check the return value of indexOf("1") for example. If it returns -1, return false, if it returns a value greater than -1, return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer this, I think this will help you, 
The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns `-1`when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns `0`. 
 so try this.
 `$.inArray(1,arr) > -1`

Answer (score 0):

So indexOf returns the position the element you are searching for is at. If no element is found, it returns -1. This is the way you can check it.

```
var arr = ["12","22","33","42"];
var match = arr.indexOf("12");
if(match > -1) {
    // Found match, at position "match"
    var element = arr[match]; // = "12"
} else {
    // Element not in array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var a = ["12","22","33","42"];
if(a.indexOf('12')!= '-1')
{
    alert("success")
}
else
{
    alert("failure")
}
```